# General-purpose getterSetter in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) for ngModel has an example for getterSetter:

```
angular.module('getterSetterExample', [])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  var _name = 'Brian';
  $scope.user = {
    name: function(newName) {
     // Note that newName can be undefined for two reasons:
     // 1. Because it is called as a getter and thus called with no arguments
     // 2. Because the property should actually be set to undefined. This happens e.g. if the
     //    input is invalid
     return arguments.length ? (_name = newName) : _name;
    }
  };
}]);
```

This is exactly what I would need, but I wouldn't like to write this part over and over again in different contexts. **Is it possible to create a generic getterSetter?** Like

```
$scope.user.name = nameGetterSetter;
```

I just can't see how that global function could get or set any specific instance without passing scope.

Comment: you mean like `var nameGetterSetter = function(newName){return arguments.length ? (_name = newName) : _name;};`?

Comment: Why would you want to have a generic getterSetter? The sole purpose of a getterSetter is to have custom logic for retrieving/storing the value.

Comment: you can simply do something like this ` $scope.user.name = newName || 'Brian;' `

Comment: @Aprillion , @pablochan , Let's assume I have a use case where `user` is used in a few controllers. At the moment `user` is populated from JSON data in each controller as it's bound to change. But in each controller `user` will act in a similar fashion, and, thus, my question.

Comment: You can use a service/factory shared by all your controllers with function getField(fieldName) and setFieldValue(fieldName, fieldValue). Inside these functions your get your JSON data, test null...etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you don't actually need to use a getterSetter. Creating a separate model for handling users would be more useful. One way to do this is to create an Angular service. Here's a contrived example:

```
// I'm using a separate module, but you don't have to
angular.module('user').factory('User', function() {

    function User(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    return User;

});
```

Now if we go back to your code:

```
angular.module('getterSetterExample', ['user'])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', 'User', function($scope, User) {
      $scope.user = new User('Brian');
  }]);
```

I've injected my "user factory" to the controller and then use it to create the user model. You can inject services into multiple controllers if needed. I suggest that you read about [services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services).

If you're using a REST API, take a look at [ngResource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource). It provides some generic functionality for retrieving and storing data.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

Sharer.js:

```
  myApp.factory('mySharer', [function () {
    var myField = 'Initialized';

    return {
        getProperty: function() {
            return myField;
        },
        setProperty: function(value) {
            myField = value;
            return myField;
        }
    };
  }]);
```

Controller.js:

```
myApp.controller("myController", ["$scope","mySharer",        
                                      function($scope, mySharer){

        $scope.myField='HellYeah!';
        mySharer.setProperty($scope.myField);

}]);
```

Hope I've been helpfull.