# how to pass parameter and get values from custom directive in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example11-production</title>


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>  
</head>
<body ng-app="docsSimpleDirective">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
  <div my-customer></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('docsSimpleDirective', [])
  .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.customer = {
      name: 'Naomi',
      address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
    };
  }])
  .directive('myCustomer', function() {
    return {
      template: 'Name: {{customer.name}} Address: {{customer.address}}'
    };
  });
})(window.angular);
```

> I want pass value to directive and based on key want to retrieve value from controller method.

pass value here `<div my-customer="FirstName"></div>`
`FirstName` is the key want to pass it to directive and get `FirstName` value from controller method.

how can i achieve this?any similar thread ?

Comment: Did you try with a factory service to handle get and set between directories?

Comment: Try looking at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30306209/general-purpose-gettersetter-in-angularjs/30310236#30310236). By the way Aluvigden's answer can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To pass values to a custom directive, you need to specify it in the directive.

```
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      myvariable: "="
    },
    template: 'Name: {{myvariable.name}} Address: {{myvariable.address}}'
  };
});
```

now you can:

```
<!-- customer is an object from your controller -->
<div my-customer myvariable="customer"></div>
```

There are different ways to pass values. You can use `@`, `=` and `&`. They all work different. Read this [great SO post regarding all the types of bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope) you can do.

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yavzcpo6/)

Remember that the `'='` means that the binding is bi-directional. It is a reference to a variable to the parent scope. In other words, when you change the variable in the directive, it will be changed in the parent scope as well.